# Magento 2 braintree verifyCard options must include a BIN

Tags: magento2.3, payment-methods, paypal, braintree, gene-braintree

**Preconditions and environment**

We are using Magento version - 2.4.6-p3 after an upgrade from 2.4.5-p1

**Steps to reproduce**

1 - Add product to the cart

2 - Go to the checkout page page

3 - Try to place order via Braintree credit card with 3D Secure Verification should be enabled

4 - We will not be able to do place order because we are getting an error on browser console

**Expected result**

The order should be placed successfully.

**Actual result**

Getting this error on browser console -

```
3d-secure.js:135 3dsecure validation failed 
n {name: 'BraintreeError', code: 'THREEDS_MISSING_VERIFY_CARD_OPTION', message: 'verifyCard options must include a BIN.', type: 'MERCHANT', details: undefined}
code: "THREEDS_MISSING_VERIFY_CARD_OPTION"
details: undefined
message: "verifyCard options must include a BIN."
name: "BraintreeError"
type: "MERCHANT"
[[Prototype]]: Error
```

Comment: Did you have any luck resolving this issue ?. I'm facing the same and wondering if you found the cause of it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check if there are any mixins for

1. vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cc-form.js
2. vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/vault.js

If you have any mixins for this, make sure in your mixin method "setCreditCardBin" is called as per the parent implementation is the above 2 files